# Simple Project in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm really struggling with the examples and documentation on ServiceStack.  I want to do something really simple but none of the examples given seem to map exactly on what I need.  I'm also thrown by the new API section on the website and whether that renders the rest of the (basic) documentation obsolete.

I'm just trying to wrap a number of database entities in a service that exposes CRUD REST and SOAP endpoints (need to retain some SOAP support for use by legacy clients/applications).

Let's call these entities

```
x:  id, description
y:  id, name
```

(they are not related in any way - think I can cope with related ones once I get my head around the very basics)

So I've built a solution:

```
MyAPI
    Global.asx
    Web.config
MyAPI.Logic
    DB Access code?
MyAPI.SeviceInterface
    MyAPiService.cs? 
MyAPI.ServiceModel
    Operations
        x.cs
        x.Response
        y.cs
        y.Response
    Types
        Don't think I need this but like to overengineer my early projects to make future changes easier
```

Hopefully this seems sensible

Given the very basic format of entity x, what is the best way to structure x.cs and MyAPIService.cs (I assume entity y would just be treated the same) to achieve basic CRUD operations for both REST and SOAP?

Small point but can I implement two GETs - one that passes in an id (and returns a specific x) and one that doesn't receive an id (and returns a list of all x's)?

I've looked at every link on stackoverflow and servicestack.net already so please no pointers to those - I think I'm just missing the point of the exisitng documentation!!

Many Thanks in Advance

Andy

Comment: Check the [readme on GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), the `Todos` class is an example of the type of DTO you want. You can probably use the same class for both the request and response (or a List of your DTO for the response), as shown in that readme.

Comment: Excellent example, seems I'd read everything else apart from that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just need a little further clarification.  The example in the readme deals with only one entity. To add a second entity (my y in explanation above) do I need another Service class or can I provide different implementations of Get, Post, Put and Delete passing in a different parameter type?

Comment: The ServiceStack framework itself doesn't care too much, so do whatever feels right to you. If the two entities are not *very* similar and closely related, I would create a second service class.